How to handle expired JWT tokens without exceptions in .NET Core?
I'm working on JWT token generation and validation in .NET Core. Here is the code I use to generate my token:
string GenerateToken()
{
    var securityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(mySecret));
    var credentials = new SigningCredentials(securityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
    var claims = new Claim[] { 
        new(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
    };

    var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

    var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor()
    {
        Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(claims),
        Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(10),
        SigningCredentials = credentials,
        Audience = "audience",
        Issuer = "issuer"
    };

    var securityToken = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
    var token = tokenHandler.WriteToken(securityToken);

    return token;
}

And here is the code to validate a token:
void ValidateToken(string token)
{
    JwtSecurityTokenHandler validationHandler = new();
    var claimsPrincipal = validationHandler.ValidateToken(token, new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        ValidIssuer = "issuer",
        ValidAudience = "audience",
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(
            Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(mySecret)),
        ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
    }, out SecurityToken securityToken);
}

When the token has expired, I receive the following exception message:

IDX10223: Lifetime validation failed. The token is expired. ValidTo
(UTC): '6/9/2024 6:21:36 AM', Current time (UTC): '6/9/2024 6:21:38
AM'.

This code sample is from a console application, but I've also tested it in a Web API, and it throws the same exception and returns a 401 status code.
I am using the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer package.
My question is: why is this exception being thrown, and how can I handle expired tokens more gracefully without exceptions?
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

The standard is to return 401 when a token is expired,
if you don't want a exception to be thrown, that's a consumer concern
say you are using angular or another .not application the consumer of the api who receive the token should be handling the unauthorized

"why is this exception being thrown" becasue "IDX10223: Lifetime validation failed. The token is expired."

Why is expires only 10 seconds?  Make time longer so it doesn't expire.

Getting exception and 401 error code should be the expected behavior as the token is invalid and we shouldn't modify the API to change the behavior, we should write custom code in the client that maybe add  a redirection to the login page so that it could create a new valid access token.  I also agree with @jdweng that we should increase the expire time because 10s is too short, especially when there's a network latency.

@TinyWang I intentionally set the time to 10 for testing purposes. What I would like to understand is why it's throwing an exception instead of saying invalid.

Firstly, I think this is the expected behavior and the best way to explain it is finding the source code, but I failed to locate the program line. And when we use an invalid token to call the secured API, 401 error code along with an error message like Lifetime validation failed. The token is expired.should be a friendly response, we can say the error message incidating a token error, but it doesn't mean the application got something wrong then it throws an exception. I don't think it's good to return 200 along with antoken expired` error message.

Let's see whether someone else could share the related source code.
